# Closest Jquery Top Level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to use the closest function correctly to remove the UL outside of the remove button.

**HTML**

```
<ul data-centreid="1"  class="deleteButton">
  <div class="remove">X</div>
   <li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $('.remove').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).closest( ".deleteButton" ).data('centreid');
       $(this).closest( ".deleteButton" ).remove();
   });
```

Comment: Which browser? It works in Chrome

Comment: Oh it does.. What the hell!

Comment: Actually it should work in any browser. There's possibly an error in code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBLST/3/)

You are actually not able to click the `.remove` div

**`Jquery`**

```
 $('.remove').click(function(){

   var id = $(this).closest( ".deleteButton" ).data('centreid');
   $(this).closest( ".deleteButton" ).remove();

});
```

**`HTML`**

```
<ul data-centreid="1"  class="deleteButton">
<div class="remove">remove</div>
<li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Markup is wrong

you can not have `div` directly inside `ul`

you need to have `li` inside `ul` than have `div`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XE2E6/)

```
<ul data-centreid="1" class="deleteButton">
    <li>
        <div class="remove"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

---

or

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XE2E6/1)

```
<div class="remove">Remove</div>
<ul data-centreid="1" class="deleteButton">
    <li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That mark is incorrect i know but its all i got to work with, I need to update the Remove button code to remove the associating ul.